# Nested forms in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

My models:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

My controller `questions_controller`:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  expose(:topic) { Topic.find(params[:topic_id]) }
  expose(:question, attributes: :question_params)
  expose(:questions) { topic.questions }

  def create
    if topic.questions.create(question_params)
      redirect_to topic
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(
      :title,
      :instructions,
      answers_attributes: [:id, :answer, :correct, :question_id, :_destroy]
    )
  end
end
```

`/questions/_form`:

```
= simple_form_for [:topic, question] do |f|
  = f.input :title, label: "Question:", placeholder: "Your question here."
  = f.input :instructions, label: "Instructions:", placeholder: "If this question requires special instructions, put them here."
  %br
  %h3
    Answers
  #answers
    = f.simple_fields_for :answers do |answer|
      = render 'answer_fields', f: answer
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add answer', f, :answers
  = f.submit class: "button small radius expand success"
```

`/questions/answer_fields`:

```
.nested_fields
  = f.input :answer
  = f.input :correct, as: :boolean
  = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f
```

`routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :topics do
    resources :questions
  end
  root to: 'topics#index'
end
```

I'm using [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to manage my nested forms.

When I go to `/topics/.:id` and press the 'Add New Question' button, it takes me to the `/topics/.:id/questions/new` path, and when I press the 'add answer' button, cocoon renders 3 new spaces for answers. Also, the items are not being deleted if I press the 'remove answer' link.

Why is the view rendering 3 answer fields?
Why is the 'remove answer' link not working?

Comment: I have a form very similar to this. So what exactly is your question? Are you asking about why the `= link_to_remove_association "remove task", f` is not working? or why is it rendering 3 new spaces for answers?

Comment: "When I go to /topics/.:id and press the 'Add New Question' button, it takes me to the /topics/.:id/questions/new path, and when I press the 'add answer' button, cocoon renders 3 new spaces for answers." this statement seems correct to me. It's exactly what should happen. your model, controller and forms look correct to me. Should the only thing we look into be why the 'remove answer' link is not working? If so, please state so